# Title of Contact Not Being Saved

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why the title and company fields for a contact are not being saved into SalesforceIQ.  I'm getting the name, email, phone, address, company, and title from a CSV.

I then run `process_contact(name, email, phone, address, company, title, all_contacts)`.  I check each contact and their name, email, phone, and address *are* being saved into SalesforceIQ but their company and title fields are *not* being saved.

When I print title in `set_contact_fields`, the correct title for each contact prints out on both lines.  I'm pretty confused at this point.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
def process_contact(name, email, phone, address, company, title, all_contacts):
    # if contact exists
    contact_id = get_id_from_contact_email(email, all_contacts)
    print 'contact_id: {}'.format(contact_id)
    if contact_id is not None:
        print 'updating contact'
        # update information
        return update_contact(name, phone, address, company, title, contact_id)
    else:
        print 'creating contact'
        # create new contact
        return create_contact(name, email, phone, address, company, title)


def create_contact(name, email, phone, address, company, title):
    contact = Contact()
    contact.email(email)
    set_contact_fields(contact, name, phone, address, company, title)
    return contact.create()


def update_contact(name, phone, address, company, title, contact_id):
    contact = Contact(contact_id)
    set_contact_fields(contact, name, phone, address, company, title)
    return contact.update()


def set_contact_fields(contact, name, phone, address, company, title):
    contact.name(name)
    contact.phone(phone)
    contact.address(address)
    contact.company(company)
    print 'title being set: ' + title
    contact.title(title)
    print 'title is set: ' + contact.title()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which python library are you using?

Comment: Is company the standard Account field or a custom field?

Comment: I could not find a python library named SalesforceIQ on pypi.python.org

Comment: @DaveHumm company is a field that comes as part of a contact object, see here: https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/python#documentation_contacts_contact-object

Comment: @abhi The library is called RelateIQ!

Answer (score 1):

From the [link](https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/python#documentation_contacts_contact-object) you've posted in the comments, just these properties are supported.

Currently, the **following properties** are supported by Contact object:

name
email
phone
address

Comment: Just noticed that.  But if you look at how they create an example Contact object, they *do* set the title and company :(

Comment: @bclayman You may want to look at other libraries, this one looks somewhat limited.

Comment: @bclayman Can we get a developer account for salesforceIQ?

Comment: @abhi Not sure what you mean...elaborate?

Comment: Just to be clear - SalesforceIQ is a product and RelateIQ is the library being used. I am not sure if any other library exists for SalesforceIQ at this time.

Comment: How can I try out salesforceIQ for free?

Comment: @abhi Oh I'm not sure how to go about that, sorry.  And yes, you're right that RelateIQ is the library being used.  So it looks like I have no way of associating a title with a contact and having it show up in a list of sales leads, eh?